# How to find the integral $\lim_n \int_{-1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}f(x)}{1+n x^2}dx$ where $f$ is continuous and integrable on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

How to find the integral $\lim_n\int_{-1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}f(x)}{1+n x^2}dx$ where $f$ is continuous and integrable on $\mathbb{R}$.

I tried to change variable $\int_{-1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}f(x)}{1+n x^2}dx=\int_{-\sqrt{n}}^\infty \frac{f(x/\sqrt{n})}{1+x^2}dx$. But $f$ may not be bounded, I guess the limit  is $f(0)\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\int_1^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n}|f(x)|}{1+n x^2}dx \le 
\int_1^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n}|f(x)|}{1+n}dx \le \frac{\sqrt{n}}{1+n} \int |f|$, and hence goes to zero.

We are left with $ I_n =\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{n}f(x)}{1+n x^2}dx $. Using the substitution $u = \arctan \sqrt{n}x$, we have $du = { \sqrt{n} \over 1 + n x^2} dx$ and so the integral becomes $I_n = \int_{- { \arctan \sqrt{n}}}^{\arctan \sqrt{n}} f ({1 \over \sqrt{n}} \tan u) du$.

Now let $g_n(u) = f ({1 \over \sqrt{n}} \tan u) 1_{(-\arctan \sqrt{n},\arctan \sqrt{n}) } (u)$, and note that $g_n(u) \to f(0)1_{(-{ \pi \over 2}, { \pi \over 2} )}(u)$,
since $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Since $f$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$, it is bounded, hence $g_n$ is uniformly bounded and hence the DCT applies.

It follows that $\lim_n I_n = \lim_n \int g_n = \pi f(0)$.

Comment: Yep, you are done,  thanks. When deal with $I_n$, we can directly use DCT.

Answer (score 4):

Split the integral:
\begin{align}
\int_{-\sqrt n}^{\infty} \frac{f(x/\sqrt n)}{1 + x^2} dx
& = \int_{-\sqrt n}^{\sqrt n} \frac{f(x/\sqrt n)}{1 + x^2} dx + \int_{\sqrt n}^{\infty} \frac{f(x/\sqrt n)}{1 + x^2}dx \\
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-\sqrt n}^{\infty} \frac{f(x/\sqrt n)}{1 + x^2} dx
& = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-\sqrt n}^{\sqrt n} \frac{f(x/\sqrt n)}{1 + x^2} dx + \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\sqrt n}^{\infty} \frac{f(x/\sqrt n)}{1 + x^2}dx.
\end{align}
The second integral will go to $0$ because
$$
\int_{\sqrt n}^\infty \left|\frac{f(x / \sqrt n)}{1 + x^2}\right| dx
\le \left(\int_{\sqrt n}^{\infty} |f(x / \sqrt n)| dx\right)
\frac{1}{1 + n}
\le \frac{C\sqrt n}{1 + n}
$$
and the right-hand side goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. ($C$ exists because $f$ is integrable.)

Next, set
$$
g_n(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{f(x/\sqrt n)}{1 + x^2} & ; x \in [-\sqrt n, \sqrt n] \\
0 & ; x \notin [-\sqrt n, \sqrt n]
\end{cases}
$$
The limit in question is $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g_n(x) dx$.
Each $|g_n|$ is bounded by $\frac{\sup_{\xi \in[-1, 1]} |f(\xi)|}{1 + x^2}$, so the dominated convergence theorem applies. (We know that $f$ is bounded in $[-1, 1]$ because it's continuous.) The pointwise limit of $g_n$ is $g(x) = \frac{f(0)}{1 + x^2}$, and its integral is $f(0)\pi$, as you speculated.

Comment: For the second integral, how do you get the first step inequality?

Comment: Oh sorry. I made a terrible mistake! Let me see if I could fix it.

Comment: Yes.............,,

Comment: @Shine I think it should make sense now...

Comment: Nothing like the mistake I made.

Comment: @copper.hat I don't recall you making any mistakes.

Comment: I'm busy trying to fix the mistake in my deleted answer :-).

Comment: How does $\int_{\sqrt{n}}^\infty f(x/\sqrt{n} dx)=\int_1^\infty f(t)\sqrt{n} dt<C$

Comment: @Shine I'm sorry. I missed another factor :P

Comment: haha, never mind.

Comment: @Shine I tend to make more mistakes when the math is less messy... :(

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to usurp you.

Comment: Ok, now it is correct.

Comment: @copper.hat I know you didn't. Don't worry :) Your answer is a lot more compact.

Comment: @Shine Haha. I know. I corrected it right before I said I missed another factor.